# Check if returned array from mysql is empty in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, count

I've been trying to do this for a while but to no avail
basically I have a function SelectRowByName that returns the mysql array result and I want to validate if it returns a record or not but it's not working. My code is:

```
$fileInfo = selectRowByName("SELECT ID,Mime,IconIMG FROM tblattachment_filetypes WHERE Active=1 AND Extension = '".$extension."'");
```

// I want to validate that $fileInfo got filled before trying to fill the below variables to avoid errors

```
$fileType = $fileInfo[1];
$fileTypeID = $fileInfo[0];
$fileIcon = $fileInfo[2];
```

I have tried using empty, isset and array count functions but they don't seem to work. Basically the query might not return any records and $fileInfo might not be filled and I want to validate that.

SelectRowByName code is:

```
      function selectRowByName($query)
      {
          global $server,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$db,$connection,$dbCon;
          $theQuery = mysql_query($query);
          $result = mysql_fetch_array($theQuery) or die(mysql_error());
          return $result;   
      }
```

Comment: Is $fileInfo always an array?

Comment: As you can see, it is filled by 3 fields from a db record. but it won't be an array if it doesn't return a record, which is what im trying to do here. I tried using the is_array function but it also didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Inside your SelectRowByName function you may use one of the following (depending on the way you access MySQL):

```
mysql_num_rows()
mysqli_stmt_num_rows()
PDOStatement::rowCount()
```

to get number of rows returned.

Comment: Can't I simply validate the returned variable?

Comment: "Simply" is not the word I would use in that case. You want working solution or your question is theoretical?

Comment: :) I want a working solution, but I want the best solution that doesn't require additional db hits if possible

Comment: mysql_num_rows() and others do not make any additional calls to RDBMS. They are working on PHP's buffer.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
function selectRowByName($query){
      $q=mysql_query($query);

      if($q!=false){
          $result=mysql_fetch_array($q);

          if(is_array($result)&&count($result)>0){
              return $result;
          }
          else{
              return false;
          }
      }
      else{
           return false;
      }
  }
```

I wouldn't exactly advise using this code though. Firstly the mysql_ functions are now deprecated so you would be better off using mysqli or PDO. The other thing is that this function is only able to return a singular row from the query.

Either way, hope this helps.

Ryan